# Ubuntu 14 upgrade problem , because i installed ROS in Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade

I try to upgrade Ubuntu to Ubuntu 16
however I have ROS in my system and I don't want to remove it
what can i do ?
I'm trying `sudo do-release-upgrade` and it fails with the following error:

```
Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This can be caused by: 
* Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. 


Restoring original system state
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to upgrade with `sudo do-release-upgrade` from 14.04 to 16.04 with installed [ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Ubuntu) packages.

The Indigo release of ROS is only available for Ubuntu 13.10 and 14.04. So you have properly Indigo installed on your system. For Ubuntu 16.04 only the Kinetic/Lunar release of ROS are available.

You can try to remove the ROS installation from your system (the packages at least), then upgrade to 16.04 and install Kinetic or Lunar. After that you have to adapt your ROS application to the new ROS release.

Since removing ROS, upgrade and reinstall ROS will create a lot of friction I would recommend to fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04.